# Sufficient electric safety protection with MOVs?

Tags: safety, three-phase, certification

I am developing a PCB that will carry 32 A currents.  In order to protect the rest of the circuit and the 3 phase load I have added some protective measures to suppress transient voltages and short  circuits.

The PCB will have to go through electric safety certification in which they do a series of high voltage tests. These tests include applying 4000V potential between all the lines in common and differential mode and also high and low temperature tests.

Are the measures I have taken correct and sufficient, or should I add additional protection? What is the most common protection mechanism that people add to their circuits to protect it?

The protective measures I have taken is connecting 14mm 620 V  TVS varistors  between all 3 phases and another set connected to ground through a 600V, 15kA gas discharge tube (2049-60-BT1LF).

The rest of the circuit is powered through the first phase and is protected by an isolated power supply and a PTC thermistor. The whole device will also be behind a dedicated type A RCD.

The standards that I need to comply with are IEC 61851-1 & IEC 61851-22 if that provides any additional information.

Here is a crude schematic of what I have currently implemented:

[image]

Comment: So all three phases are connected together, or what? You do connect 350VDC varistors in between phases that have +/-560V peak voltage??!!

Comment: The MOVs between phases are for suppresing transient voltages. They shouldnt be connected together unless a catastrophic failiure happens

Comment: Need fuses to protect in case of shorted MOVs. I don't know these standard requirement but if you need to test at 4kV I'd say you need to meet category II overvoltage at 600V. It's quite a complex design to do